# Python - need help looping a list through functions using 4 different ranges (0-25, 0-100, 0-1000, 0-10000)

Tags: python, function, sorting, loops

Python Version - 3.3.2

I am writing a Python program that sets a list equal to a range of numbers (0-25), shuffles these numbers randomly and then sorts these numbers using four different sorting functions: bubble sort, selection sort, python sort, and insertion sort. There is also a timer function at the end of the program that times how long each function takes to sort the range of random numbers.

I need a way to change the range from (0-25) to (0-100) then (0-1000) and finally (0-10000).
Each time it loops through a range of numbers and outputs how much time it takes to sort the list for each sorting function.

Here is an example of the code:

```
    import random
    import time

    # Sets myList equal to a range with a range from 0-25
    myList = list(range(0,25))
    # Randomly shuffles the list of numbers between 0-25
    random.shuffle(myList)

    # Bubble Sort
    def bubbleSort(myList):
    ...(insert code)...

    # Selection Sort
    def selectionSort(myList):
    ...(insert code)...

    # Python Sort
    def pythonSort(myList):
    ...(insert code)...

    # Insertion Sort
    def insertionSort(myList):
    ...(insert code)...

    # Timer
    def timer(array, func):
    ...(insert code)...
    print("Time needed for", func.__name__, 'to sort',len(array),'items: ',diff)

    timer(myList, selectionSort)
    timer(myList, bubbleSort)
    timer(myList, pythonSort)
    timer(myList, insertionSort)
```

So again, my question is, how do I set the list equal to (0-25) loop through all of the sorting functions, output the time for each sorting function to complete, then change the list to equal (0-100), loop through all of the functions, output the time for each function and so on for (0-1000) and (0-100000)?

Comment: `for length in [25, 100, 1000, 100000]:` ...

Comment: @wjl Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed. I figured it was a simple line of code, however, I was over thinking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from random import shuffle


def timer(data, sortfn):
    start = datetime.now()
    sortfn(data)
    end = datetime.now()
    return end - start

def tester():
    lengths = (25, 100, 1000, 10000)
    sortfns = (selectionSort, bubbleSort, pythonSort, insertionSort)
    for length in lengths:
        myList = list(range(length))
        shuffle(myList)
        for sortfn in sortfns:
            # Take a deep copy of the shuffled data
            shuffled = myList[:]
            # Sort the shuffled data
            elapsed = timer(shuffled, sortfn)
            print("{0}({1}): {2}".format(sortfn.__name__, length, elapsed))

tester()
```

Comment: I just tested the code you provided with my sorting functions and I can definitely tell the difference. This fixed the problem you described where it would just sort the already sorted list. The time that each algorithm runs seems reasonable rather than increasing and decreasing in a random fashion. I appreciate the help and I will continue to play around with my code and the code you provided to achieve my desired format. Thank you for taking your time to help me! Also, thank you to the other people who helped as well!

Answer (score 2):

As wjl suggests

```
for length in [25, 100, 1000, 10000]:
    myList = range(length) # range(25) is equal to range(0,25)

    timer(myList, selectionSort) #assuming that selectionSort doesn't alter myList
    timer(myList, bubbleSort)
    timer(myList, pythonSort)
    timer(myList, insertionSort)
```

Comment: wjl told me exactly what I needed, but thank you showing how I would implement it. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Presumably,one of the side effects of this is that the original list becomes sorted, so after `selectionSort` sorts the unsorted list, the other routines operate on a sorted list.

Comment: Yes, probably it does happen, solution is deepcopying the list in the sort or altering my code so that myList is overwritten after each call to timer()

Comment: @hughdbrown I haven't had to opportunity to check to see if the other sort methods are just going off of the sorted list for selection sort, if they are, how can I make it to where they go off the original unsorted list?

Comment: @windwarrior do you have a solution that can fix it if other sort functions are just working off of the sorted list from the selection function and not the original unsorted list?

Comment: you could use copy.deepcopy(myList), that would certainly fix your issue, or maybe a shallow copy is enough for this case - copy.copy(myList) - but thats something you have to test ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your arguments to range in a list of tuples then just expand the tuple:

```
>>> ranges=[(0,10),(15,20),(200,210,2)]   # correspond to start, stop, step in range
>>> for r in ranges:
...    for i in range(*r):
...       # do whatever...
```

Or:

```
>>> ranges=[(0,10),(15,20),(200,210,2)]   # correspond to start, stop, step in range
>>> for r in ranges:
...    your_list=list(range(*r))
...    # do whatever...
```